# Mage exception: Invalid block type

Tags: magento-1.9, exception-error

I'm using Magento 1.9.4 and after uninstalling a 3rd party module, I keep getting this error in exception.log:

> Mage_Core_Exception: Invalid block type: Mage_Dailydeals_Block_Widget
>   in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:598

```
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block type...')
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Mage_Dailydeals...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('dailydeals/widg...', 'bb7635818b4ed88...')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('dailydeals/widg...', 'bb7635818b4ed88...')
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/.modman/magento_corefixes/src/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /var/www/html/.modman/magento_corefixes/src/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/index.php(83): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#16 {main}
```

Removed everything from DB and checked the code for any remaining PHP file but did not find anything.

Can someone please help me remove this bug?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your layout xml you've got a `type="dailydeals/widget"` entry.  Because the extension no longer exists magento is falling back to checking for Dailydeals Block Widget in app/code/core/Mage/Dailydeals/Block/Widget

So either see if you can track down the layout xml entry.  This could also be in database somewhere.  Or create `app/code/core/Mage/Dailydeals/Block/Widget.php` or perhaps better `app/code/local/Mage/Dailydeals/Block/Widget.php`

```php
class Mage_Dailydeals_Block_Widget {

}
```

to stop the error

Could be a cache issue though.  I'm assuming you've cleared all the caches after removing the plugin.